# Why does the size of my input box increase when I start typing

Tags: html, css

When I start typing inside the input, the buttons and the input box increase in size and then decrease again when I remove the text.

HTML

```
<input class="input input-lg"type="text" placeholder="Enter your username">
```

CSS

```
input{
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
}
```

Container div containing the input form CSS

```
.container{
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z71sb6vq/

Question has been answered by @llw in the comments

Solution: Removed `justify-content: center;` tag from grid container.

Comment: All relevant code should be in the question itself, not an external link, and I don't see the behavior you're describing in that fiddle either.

Comment: I've visited the fiddle, and the text input always stays the same size, irrelevant of the amount of text inside it. Could you describe your problem in more detail?

Comment: Basically the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/60982171/7148391, make your grid items display block or define a width for the grid column, Also why not use flexbox for this ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak The solution to that question is already in my code.

Comment: i have noticed that input box increases slightly when inputting text,  and commenting out  `justify-content: center;` in .container{}  class seems to fix it. ( i'm using Opera)

Comment: @Run_Script I can recreate the problem only on Chrome. Other browsers don't change the size of the input box when there is text inside it. I will add a gif of the problem in a minute

Comment: @YashBurshe It's not we're talking about the width which is the column and you only defining row height

Comment: @lww that seemed to fix it. Thanks for your help! What is the reason it does that though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ignore my comments i didn't go through everything properly :3*

I'll try to explain why this is happening for future readers, It may not be 100% accurate.

I didn't even notice you had `padding:5%` Which is the main problem. Specifically the relative unit `%`.

---

First the issue doesn't have anything to with `justify-content: center;`

```css
[grid] {
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: inline-grid;
}

input {
  padding: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div grid>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

*To mimic the issue without `justify-content` i made the grid container inline so the container as well as the column depend on the input.*

The `justify-content` property aligns columns within the container, the value `center` centers the column in the middle horizontally, it's width then depends on the content then the left over space is distributed evenly on each side.

Removing it worked because the column width doesn't depend on the content anymore it's now 
equal to the grid container's width and the relative unit is calculated accurately.

---

When it comes to parent elements depending on their content to define their width relative units is an issue.

1. Parent width depend on child width.
2. child's padding depend on parent width
3. padding adds to the elements width

You can see there will be an infinite loop of calculations.

The calculation steps goes as follow

1. Parent width is ignored.
2. Calculate content width.
3. Go back set parent width based on content.
4. Calculate padding for the child.
5. Doesn't go back to adjust parent's width (avoid infinite loop)

Most browsers stop there, but not chrome. *Did you try running your code in FireFox ?*

---

**Why input and button grow in size when you start typing and go back to normal when you delete everything**

Input have a size attribute which defines the number of visible characters before it starts to overflow. Default is `20` this number is not accurate because not all fonts have same width characters so don't expect exactly `20` characters.

If you were to change the font to monospace(all characters are equal size) and type exactly 20 chars the input will grow to fit all those 20 chars.

```css
[grid] {
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: inline-grid;
}

input {
  padding: 5%;
  font-family:monospace;
}
```

```html
<p>Type exatly 20 chars and see the input keep growing until it can fit all of them</p>

<div grid>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Now copy all those chars wait for the input to go back to normal size then just past them in you'll see that some of them are cut off because it didn't grow.

```css
[grid] {
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: inline-grid;
}

input {
  padding: 5%;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<p>a set value to mimic the paste</p>

<div grid>
  <input type="text" value="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa">
</div>
```

Going back to relative units,

The input grow because after the calculation for the width of the container and padding, The visible characters size is not considered And when you start typing chrome tries to correct it (other browsers ignore this) making the input grow which makes the parent grow as well which makes the buttons grow because they follow the width of their parent.

Comment: @karel That's a good idea, on it.

Answer (score 0):

You were used padding: 5% in the .input-lg class. Remove it and give input box height as suitable value.
`.input-lg{
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 2rem;
}`

Answer (score -1):

Try set fixed width to input like this, for example 100px

```
input {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem

Comment: What kind of web browser you are using?